# How to edit basic xml file to execute something

Tags: xml, shell, jenkins, groovy

I have this xml file "`build-samples.xml`", and I want to edit this portion of it-

```
<target name="extract" unless="host.isWindows">
        <echo>#####################################################################################</echo>
        <echo># Extracting ${loads.dir}/${deploy.version}/${clientTar} to ${build_samples_dir}</echo>
        <echo>#####################################################################################</echo>
        <exec
            dir="${build_samples_dir}"
            executable="gunzip"
            failonerror="true">
            <arg line="${clientTar}.tar.gz"/>
        </exec>
        <exec
            dir="${build_samples_dir}"
            executable="${GNU_TAR}"
            failonerror="true">
            <arg line="-xf ${clientTar}.tar"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
```

and add this line in it-

```
sh " sed -i'' -e 's/SIXTY_FOUR_COMPAT:=-m32/SIXTY_FOUR_COMPAT:=/g' ${build_samples_dir}/Linux-native/opt/client-100.0.38.601/Intro/Makefile
```

**What I want to do-** This build-samples.xml basically extract a tar.gz file into a directory called "build_samples_dir", this tar file includes a Makefile that I want to edit, using sed

I cant directly edit tar file, so this is the next best thing I have.

**My question:-** How can I edit this xml file to have this sed command execute after it extracts that tar file.

Comment: `How can I edit this xml file` use notepad or vim.. you have example with exec section - just follow it.

Comment: I cant use notepad or vim as this file exists as I said inside a tar file that I copy over to my workspace on jenkins from a server that is locked and im only allowed to copy over this single tar file, the only way for me to do this is to edit the xml file i mentioned above

Comment: so, do you need to do it using groovy in jenkins pipeline? if yes - you just need to use 3 steps - readFile, change content, then writeFile. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace